# After removing libglib2.0 and fpc can't install it back and can't install other packages and dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management

Input:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1 378 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-dev (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.37.6); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcairo2-dev:
 libcairo2-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev; however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcairo2-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpango1.0-dev:
 libpango1.0-dev depends on libcairo2-dev (>= 1.12.10); however:
  Package libcairo2-dev is not configured yet.
 libpango1.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.34.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpango1.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libatk1.0-dev:
 libatk1.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.31.2); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libatk1.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-dev:
 libgtk2.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libgtk2.0-dev depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libgtk2.0-dev depends on libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20); however:
  Package libpango1.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libgtk2.0-dev depends on libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2); however:
  Package libatk1.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libgtk2.0-dev depends on libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1); however:
  Package libcairo2-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgtk2.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fp-units-gtk2-3.0.0:
 fp-units-gtk2-3.0.0 depends on libgtk2.0-dev; however:
  Package libgtk2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fp-units-gtk2-3.0.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fpc-3.0.0:
 fpc-3.0.0 depends on fp-units-gtk2-3.0.0 (>= 3.0.0+dfsg-2); however:
  Package fp-units-gtk2-3.0.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fpc-3.0.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fpc:
 fpc depends on fpc-3.0.0 (= 3.0.0+dfsg-2); however:
  Package fpc-3.0.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fpc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpulse-dev:amd64:
 libpulse-dev:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-dev; however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpulse-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsdl1.2-dev:
 libsdl1.2-dev depends on libpulse-dev; however:
  Package libpulse-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsdl1.2-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:amd64:
 libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:amd64 depends on libsdl1.2-dev (>= 1.2.14~); however:
  Package libsdl1.2-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-dev
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
 libcairo2-dev
 libpango1.0-dev
 libatk1.0-dev
 libgtk2.0-dev
 fp-units-gtk2-3.0.0
 fpc-3.0.0
 fpc
 libpulse-dev:amd64
 libsdl1.2-dev
 libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the error message tells you the reason and what to do:

*error processing package `libglib2.0-dev` (--configure):
 package is in a **very bad inconsistent state**; you should
 **reinstall** it before attempting configuration*

Everything else is a consequence of the above. `libglib2.0-dev` is a dependency for the other packages.

Reinstall `libglib2.0-dev` :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libglib2.0-dev
```